# Automatically adds "amp%3b " to query string

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

When i send the query string's from view to controller "amp%3b" is added to one query string.
Other one coming exactly. how to remove the appended text in controller.
Here is my code

View:

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("SortBy", "Product", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.Hidden("CategoryId", Convert.ToString(Model.CategoryId))
    @Html.DropDownList("SortBy", ViewData["SortBy"] as SelectList, "-- Sort By Price --", new { onchange = "this.form.submit()" })

}
```

Controller Code:

```
Public ActionResult SortBy()
      {string sortStatus = Request.QueryString["sortBy"];
        int BrandId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["BrandId"]);}
```

values coming like this

```
Request.QueryString {sortBy=1&amp%3bBrandId=559}
```

i want to remove the text "amp%3b".
thanks in advance.

Comment: Where and how are you using the result of this `@Url.Action` call? Are you passing it to another helper? Or are you using some javascript or something? I suspect that this is where the problem is. Url.Action only generates an url, the question is how are you calling the controller action.

Comment: I'm not using any java script function. the controller code is mentioned above.

Comment: Then where is this Url.Action variable used in your view? In order to get to your controller action something must send an HTTP request.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov i have already placed the Url.Action under the heading "View:" above.

Comment: So this generates a simple string inside your HTML. Did you do this inside an `<a>` or a `<form>` tag? The `Url.Action` simply returns a string. It doesn't call any controller action. In your question you have shown some controller action but haven't explained how is this action being called.

Comment: at the time of form submitting we are calling that controller action.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov just now i updated the code...